# Take a global Screenshot

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I want to capture a screenshot of my App, but my layout is transparent! So I want also the background image to appear (for example the android luncher etc.).

In the beginning I captured it like this :

```
public Bitmap screenshot_menu()
{
    RelativeLayout r1;

    r1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_MAIN);
    View v1 = r1.getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();


    return bm;
}
```

But this only takes Screenshot of my Buttons,ImageViews,Textviews etc. of my RelativeLayout.I also want to appear everything in the background. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: "How can I achive this ?" -- root the device and use the various approaches for taking screenshots on rooted devices. Or, use the new screenshot API in Android 5.0, though this requires user approval.

Comment: Come on ! I dont want to force the user to root his device because of a screenshot ?

Comment: Then use the new screenshot API on Android 5.0. By definition, what you are asking for is the ability to spy on the UI of another activity, whatever you happen to be on top of. This has privacy implications.